# Laravel eloquent select 1:n to 1:1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem of understanding in Laravel eloquent. 
I got 4 tables in mysql:

[image]

the id of classes A and B are the same. The id of classes A and C are the same. The identifier of class A can either be in table B or in table C.

Translated into model ORM:

```
class Utilisateurs extends Model
{
    public function as()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(A::class);
    }
}

class A extends Model
{
    public function utilisateur()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(utilisateur::class);
    }

    public function b()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(B::class);
    }

    public function c()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(C::class);
    }
}

class B extends Model
{
    public function A()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(A::class);
    }
}

class C extends Model
{
    public function A()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(A::class);
    }
}
```

So, my question is if there is a way to access table B from the user table

I know one way to do it.

```
public function getB(int $id)
{
    $user = Utilisateur::find($id);
    $bs = array();
    if($user){
        $user->a()-each(function($item){
            $b = $item->b()->first();
            if($b){$bs[] = $b}
        })
    }
    return $bs;
}
```

Do you know another way to do it?

Thank.

> the post is resolved: the best way is to use the relationship : [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationships?

Comment: @thisiskelvin - thank you I forgot to read this relation, It could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like thisiskelvin suggested in the comments, you could take a look at [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

Otherwise, you could use Laravel's [Collection methods](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html) as follows :

```
$user = Utilisateurs::find($id);
$bs = $user->as()->map(function($a){
  return $a->b()->first();
})->filter(function($b){
  return $b;
})->toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
$utilisateur = Utilisateur::find(id);

// all the b models which belongs to the utilisateur.
$bs = $utilisateur->as->map->b;

// all the c models which belongs to the utilisateur.
$cs = $utilisateur->as->map->c
```

Note that `$bs` and `$cs` are collection, not a single model.

**Edit**

use `optional()` function in case of null `as`

```
$bs = optional($utilisateur->as)->map->b;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$utilisateur = Utilisateur::findorFail(id);
// Each and every B which belongs to the utilisateur.
$bs = $utilisateur->as->map->b;
// Each and every C which belongs to the utilisateur.
$cs = $utilisateur->as->map->c
```

This will do the trick.